# Bootstrap Dropdown menu not Fit to Container Class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

hi i created bootstrap navbar for my wordpress theme my navbar fit to the window
but i used `container` and `row` class to set the texts within the container width but when i click on `Collection` Dropdown text the dropdown menu appear fit to the window why? i want the dropdown menu fit to the container menu or fit to the `yellow` div.

HOW I CAN DO THIS?

for show my navbar see this link
http://jsfiddle.net/rerraw/bs2wke9r/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempt for solving my problem only i added new grid class to my code and i solved my problem

i added `<div class='col-sm-12'>codes here</div>`
after this the dropdwon menu fit to the container